# How to solve for X in this equation?

Tags: problem-solving

$$n * x * cos(\frac{\pi}2 * \frac{x}{x+b}) + c = y$$

How would I get X on one side of the equation instead of y?
Normally I work the equation forwards knowing X. The other variables are constants.

for example:
$$0.000025 * 1000 * cos(\frac{\pi}2 * \frac{1000}{1000+7000}) + 0.30 = y$$
$$y = 0.32452$$

What id like to know is given y how do i solve for x?
$$0.000025 * x * cos(\frac{\pi}2 * \frac{x}{x+7000}) + 0.30 = 0.32452$$
$$x = ?$$
where x > 0

Comment: Are you sure that there is $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\color{red}{\cdot}\frac{x}{x+b}\right)$ instead of $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\color{red}{+}\frac{x}{x+b}\right)$?

Comment: I am 100% sure. why what does that mean?

Comment: I thought if there was $+$ instead of $\cdot$, you could apply some of the formulas like $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+\beta)=\ldots$. But I don't know if it's the proper method to solve that kind of equation. Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: Please consult this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  As written, your question is difficult to read.

Comment: your third equation has no solutions for $x$

Comment: is there multiple solutions for x? how is there no solution when I can plug in x = 1000 and get the solution for the 3rd equation? if there were more information could it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the equation contains at the same time polynomial and trigonometric functions, there is no explicit solution for the root(s). This is already the case for the equation $x=\cos(x)$.

Then, you need to consider numerical methods and probably one of the simplest will be Newton method which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Let us play with $$f(x)=0.000025\,  x\, \cos(\frac{\pi}2 \, \frac{x}{x+7000}) + 0.30 - 0.34567$$ in order to change from the initial problem (you already know the answer).

If you plot the function over a large range (say from $x=0$ to $x=5000$), you would "see" that there is a root close to $x=2000$. So, let us use $x_0=2000$ and $$f'(x)=0.000025 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2 (x+7000)}\right)-0.000025 x \left(\frac{\pi }{2
   (x+7000)}-\frac{\pi  x}{2 (x+7000)^2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2
   (x+7000)}\right)$$ and start applying Newton method; this will generate the following iterates $$x_1=1937.90383948004$$ $$x_2=1938.14506264438$$ $$x_3=1938.14506627915$$ which is the solution for fifteen significant figures.